# Find Laplace transform of $t-\pi$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, initial-value-problems, step-function

I am dealing with an Initial Value Problem of a step function:

$$
y'' + y = 
\begin{cases}
\cos t, &\text{ if }0\le t \lt \pi\\
t-\pi,&\text{ if }\pi \le t \lt \infty
\end{cases}
$$

I am trying to solve this using Laplace transforms.

The Laplace transform of $\cos(t)$ is $\mathscr{L}\{\cos t\}=\frac{s}{s^2 + 1}$, using the Laplace elementary transforms.

But I cannot find the Laplace transform of $t - \pi$.

There is no elementary transform I can use.

Comment: Laplace transform is linear, and for a monomial you have $L(x^n)=n!/s^{n+1}$

Comment: So what is the transform when i have t-π?

Comment: @user1584421 For equations, please refer to this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Use the shift theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\lap}{\mathscr{L}}\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}$The Heaviside function $H_a(t)$ is defined as

\begin{equation}
 H_a(t) = \begin{cases}
           0, &\text{ if } t\leq a
           \\
           1, &\text{ otherwise}
          \end{cases}
\end{equation}

The Laplace transform of $H_a$ is 
\begin{equation}
 (\lap{} H_a)(s) = \frac{e^{-as}}{s}.
\end{equation}

This function is defined for $s\in\C$ with $\Re(s)>0$.

Let us denote the right hand side of your ODE by $u(t)$. Then, you can verify that

$$
u(t) = \cos t \cdot H_0(t) + (t-\pi-\cos t)H_\pi(t)
$$

Define $u_1(t)=\cos t$ and $u_2(t)=t-\pi-\cos t$.

The Laplace transform of $u_1(t)$ is $\frac{s}{s^2+1}$. For the second term, we need to use the fact that $\cos(t-\pi)=-\cos t$, therefore

$$
u_2(t) = (t-\pi +\cos(t-\pi))H_{\pi}(t)
$$

We can now use the property

$$
\lap\{f(t-a)H_a(t)\}(s) = e^{-as}F(s),
$$

where $F(s) = (\lap f)(s)$.

I will leave the last bit to you.